# Partial Update Support on Azure DocumentDb with MongoDB protocol

Tags: mongodb, azure, azure-cosmosdb

Does the "Azure DocumentDB with protocol support for MongoDB" which is in preview support partial update of data?

I have seen in documentation that DocumentDb that does not support. But could not find any information on this.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Yes, even though it's not supported for direct to DocumentDB API, when using the MongoDB protocol support, incremental operations are supported. [Here](https://azure.microsoft.com/en-us/documentation/articles/documentdb-mongodb-guidelines/) is confirmation on the Azure page, in particular, "This includes support for field, array, bitwise and isolation updates as specified by MongoDB [Update operator specification](https://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/operator/update/). For the Update operators that need multiple document manipulations, DocumentDB provides full ACID semantics with snapshot isolation."

Comment: I followed the link labeled "Here" and could find no traces of the sentence quoted.  Can you take a look to make sure they did not take that part down, and if not provide more specific description of where to find that?   If it really is supported via MongoDB driver, someone should report that on the UserVoice feature request for Partial Updates to documentdb.

Answer (score -1):

**DocumentDB** (*Cosmos*) does support partial updates via stored procedure. Not sure why this isn't more widely documented.

We use the update operator [provided in Cosmos DB samples on github](https://github.com/Azure/azure-documentdb-js-server/blob/master/samples/stored-procedures/update.js) via the **DocumentDB API**. Sending in the `document ID` and corresponding command (`$push`, `$set`, etc.) provides similar functionality to Mongo partial updates and makes for much better performance and use of RUs (**request units**).

Comment: the update operator in DocumentDB API replaces the document with the content provided. it does not do a partial update of the document.

if you send only 1 updated property and say update, your new document will end up having only 1 property, all other properties will have been dropped. very different.